# Heroku web process timeout while running a daemon server of node.js backed with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, daemon

I have running a daemon server to post the social network feeds on scheduled time.

Currently, I have issue while running daemon server which is written in node.js and express framework backed with mongodb.

Please see the following error which I got from heroku logs command.

```
←[36m2014-11-05T12:07:26.934753+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Daemon worker process is online.
←[36m2014-11-05T12:07:28.147952+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Starting daemon server
←[36m2014-11-05T12:07:28.230621+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m APN agent connected.
←[36m2014-11-05T12:07:27.730718+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Successfully connected to MongoDB
←[36m2014-11-05T12:08:27.375215+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[36m2014-11-05T12:07:23.455341+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[36m2014-11-05T12:08:26.523383+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
←[36m2014-11-05T12:08:26.523870+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping process with SIGKILL
←[36m2014-11-05T12:08:27.369727+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 137
```

As you can see that daemon server script run successfully but after that Heroku log showing me the boot timeout error.

```
var cluster = require('cluster')

if(cluster.isMaster){

    cluster.fork()

    cluster.on('online', function(worker){
        console.log('Daemon worker process is online.')
    })

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker){
        console.log('Daemon worker process has died. Booting another.')
        cluster.fork()
    })

} else {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    var mongoDbURI
    if(process.argv.indexOf('localdb') != -1){
        mongoDbURI = 'mongodb://[IP]/[appname]'
    } else {
        //mongoDbURI = 'mongodb://[db url]'
        mongoDbURI = '[db url]'
    }

    var mongoDbOptions = {}
    if(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
        mongoDbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI
    if(process.env.MONGODB_OPTIONS)
        mongoDbOptions = JSON.stringify(process.env.MONGODB_OPTIONS)

    var Agenda = require('agenda')
    var agenda = new Agenda()
        .database(mongoDbURI, 'daemonTasks')
        .processEvery('1 minute')

    //On termination of daemon, gracefully shut down jobs
    function gracefulShutdown() {
        agenda.stop(function() {
            console.log("Shutting down daemon server")
            process.exit(0)
        })
    }

    process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulShutdown)
    process.on('SIGINT' , gracefulShutdown)

    var fs = require('fs-extra')


    mongoose.connect(mongoDbURI, mongoDbOptions)

    var db = mongoose.connection
    db.on('error', function(err){
        //If the database can not be connected to, die
        console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB\r\n", err)
        process.exit()
    })
    db.once('open', function(){
        //Connection successful
        console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB")

        //Begin loading our schema
        require('./Models/models')(mongoose, function(err, models){

            //Set up the agenda piece
            var Agenda = require('agenda')
            models.Agenda = new Agenda()
                .database(mongoDbURI, 'daemonTasks')

            // Connect to the Apple Push Notification Service
            models.APNAgent = require('./Modules/apnAgent')(models)

            if(err){
                console.log("Error loading models\r\n", err)
                process.exit()
            }

            var async = require('async')
            fs.readdir('./Daemons/', function(err, files){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                    cb(err)
                } else {
                    async.each(files, function(file, cb){
                        fs.lstat('./Daemons/' + file, function(err, stat){
                            if(err){
                                cb(err)
                            } else {
                                if(stat.isFile()){
                                    var daemon = require('./Daemons/' + file)(models)
                                    agenda.define(daemon.name, daemon.options, daemon.job)
                                    cb(null)
                                } else {
                                    cb(err)
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }, function(err){
                        if(err){
                            console.log("Error starting daemon server: ", err)
                            return
                        }

                        console.log("Starting daemon server")
                        agenda.start()
                    })
                }
            })

        })
    })

}
```

I have researched on web and found some solutions which suggest for this problem is to increase the web process time but did not find the place on Heroku where I can set this value.